# Why is PermutationProduct not yielding anything?

Tags: permutation

When I am trying to compute some products of permutations in S_48, it is somehow not working.

Here is my code:

```
PermutationProduct[{Cycles[{{40, 35, 33, 38}, {37, 34, 36, 39}, {46, 3, 19, 27}, {44, 5, 21, 29}, {41, 8, 24, 32}}], 
Cycles[{{43, 41, 46, 48}, {42, 44, 47, 45}, {1, 35, 32, 14}, {2, 37, 31, 12}, {3, 40, 30, 9}}]}]
```

But it gives:

```
{Cycles[{{3, 19, 27, 46}, {5, 21, 29, 44}, {8, 24, 32, 41}, {33, 38, 
40, 35}, {34, 36, 39, 37}}], Cycles[{{1, 35, 32, 14}, {2, 37, 31, 12}, {3, 40, 30, 9}, {41, 46, 
48, 43}, {42, 44, 47, 45}}]}
```

which is literally the same, but it is definitely not it.

Also, when I am doing:

`PermutationOrder[{Cycles[{{3, 19, 27, 46}, {5, 21, 29, 44}, {8, 24, 32, 41}, {33, 38, 40, 35}, {34, 36, 39, 37}}],    Cycles[{{1, 35, 32, 14}, {2, 37, 31, 12}, {3, 40, 30, 9}, {41, 46, 48, 43}, {42, 44, 47, 45}}]}]`

It yields:

```
PermutationOrder[{Cycles[{{3, 19, 27, 46}, {5, 21, 29, 44}, {8, 24, 
 32, 41}, {33, 38, 40, 35}, {34, 36, 39, 37}}], Cycles[{{1, 35, 32, 14}, {2, 37, 31, 12}, {3, 40, 30, 9}, {41, 46, 
 48, 43}, {42, 44, 47, 45}}]}]
```

which is literally the same as well!!!

Can someone help to point out the mistakes I made? I use Mathematica 12.1

Comment: Welcome to MMA SE! The syntax for `PermutationProduct` is `PermutationProduct[a, b, ...]`, not `PermutationProduct[{a, b, ...}]`—it takes in multiple arguments, not a single argument that's a list. Try `PermutationProduct[Cycles[{{40, 35, 33, 38}, {37, 34, 36, 39}, {46, 3, 19, 27}, {44, 5, 21, 29}, {41, 8, 24, 32}}], 
 Cycles[{{43, 41, 46, 48}, {42, 44, 47, 45}, {1, 35, 32, 14}, {2, 37, 31, 12}, {3, 40, 30, 9}}]]`. (If you have a list of cycles `a = {Cycle[...], Cycle[...], ...}`, you can use `PermutationProduct @@ a` to replace the `List` head.)

Comment: OHHHHHH it is working!!!

Comment: Thank you haha!

Comment: No problem! FYI this question will likely be closed because it was a syntax error and isn't "looking for an answer" anymore, but don't let that discourage you from asking more questions—it's just standard site practice :)